# unable to retrieve radio button value

Tags: php, forms

I have a form and am unable to retrieve the values of radio buttons using php. I've scoured SO and can find lots of questions like this one, but none of the answers seem to help.

Form:

```
        <form method="post" action="wpurse.php" name="contactform" id="weddingform">

        <fieldset>
        <h4>Wedding Details</h4>
        <label for="bname" accesskey="A"><span class="required">*</span> Bride&rsquo;s name</label>
        <input name="bname" type="text" id="bname" size="30" value="" />

        <label for="gname" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Groom&rsquo;s name</label>
        <input name="gname" type="text" id="gname" size="30" value="" />

        <label for="weddate" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span> Wedding date (DD/MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input  name="weddate" type="text" id="weddate" />

        <label for="venue" accesskey="D"><span class="required">*</span> Venue</label>
        <input type="text" id="venue" name="venue"/>

        <label for="guestsno" accesskey="D"><span class="required">*</span> Number of guests</label>
        <input type="text" id="guestsno" name="guestsno"/>

        <h4>Bride &amp; Groom Details</h4>
    <label for="address" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*</span> Contact address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />

        <label for="bemail" accesskey="F"><span class="required">*</span> Bride&rsquo;s email</label>
        <input name="bemail" type="text" id="bemail" size="30" value="" />

        <label for="bphone" accesskey="G"><span class="required">*</span> Bride&rsquo;s phone</label>
        <input name="bphone" type="text" id="bphone" size="30" value="" />

        <label for="gemail" accesskey="H"><span class="required">*</span> Groom&rsquo;s email</label>
        <input name="gemail" type="text" id="gemail" size="30" value="" />

        <label for="gphone" accesskey="I"><span class="required">*</span> Groom&rsquo;s phone</label>
        <input name="gphone" type="text" id="gphone" size="30" value="" />

        <label>Will you require invitation inserts?</label>
        <label for="inserts0"> YES</label>
        <input type="radio" id="inserts0" name="inserts" value="Yes" class="inscheck" onclick="toggleAdditionalElements(this.value);"/>
        <label for="inserts1"> NO</label>
        <input type="radio" id="inserts1" name="inserts" value="No" class="inscheck" onclick="toggleAdditionalElements(this.value);"/>

        <div id="AdditionalElements" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="qty" accesskey="I">Quantity required</label>
                    <input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" value="" />
        </div>


        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span> Your comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span> Are you human?</p>

        <label for="verify" accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
        <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

        </fieldset>

        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleAdditionalElements(val) {
        if(val == "Yes")
            jQuery("#AdditionalElements").show(200);
        else
            jQuery("#AdditionalElements").hide(200);
    }
</script>
```

PHP handling:

```
    <?php    
if(!$_POST) exit;

function isEmail($bemail) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$bemail));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$bname     = $_POST['bname'];
$gname     = $_POST['gname'];
$weddate    = $_POST['weddate'];
$venue    = $_POST['venue'];
$guestsno    = $_POST['guestsno'];
$address    = $_POST['address'];
$bemail    = $_POST['bemail'];
$bphone   = $_POST['bphone'];
$gemail    = $_POST['gemail'];
$gphone   = $_POST['gphone'];
$inserts    =$_POST['inserts'];
$qty   = $_POST['qty'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($bname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter the Bride&rsquo;s name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if (trim($gname) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter the Groom&rsquo;s name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($weddate) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the wedding date (DD/MM/YYYY).</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($venue) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the wedding venue.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($guestsno) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter an approx number of guests.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($address) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the best postal address to contact the Bride and/or Groom.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($bemail) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address for the Bride.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($bphone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number for the Bride.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($gemail) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address for the Groom.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($gphone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number for the Groom.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($bphone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The Bride&rsquo;s phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($gphone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The Groom&rsquo;s phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($bemail)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address for the Bride, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($gemail)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address for the Groom, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if (trim($inserts) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please indicate if you will require invitation inserts</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($subject) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}   

$address = "email@address.com";

$e_subject = 'Wedding purse registration - ' . $bname . '.';

$e_body = "Details below" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $bemail or via phone $bphone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $bemail" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $bemail" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$bname</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#weddingform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message_box").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message_box').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        bname: $('#bname').val(),
        gname: $('#gname').val(),
        weddate: $('#weddate').val(),
        venue: $('#venue').val(),
        guestsno: $('#guestsno').val(),
        address: $('#address').val(),
        bemail: $('#bemail').val(),
        bphone: $('#bphone').val(),
        gemail: $('#gemail').val(),
        gphone: $('#gphone').val(),
        inserts: $('#inserts').val(),
        qty: $('#qty').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message_box').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message_box').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    });
    return false;
});
```

});

I understand that it could be a [toggle issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086825/radio-button-value-not-in-post), but even when I toggle the radios I still get "nothing was selected".

The form works perfectly without the radio buttons, so the problem is definitely with them.

Comment: Can you post the entire form?  What do you get when you print `$_POST`?

Comment: Thanks Marek, I have posted entire form.

Comment: Do you have any other PHP code before what you posted that could be messing things up?  As it is now, this works just fine for me (copy/paste without any changes).

Comment: I don't think anything else is messing it up - without the buttons the form seems to work fine. But I've added all my code just in case. I've certainly made stupid mistakes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inserts: $('#inserts').val(),` that's your problem right there.  You don't have an input with id 'inserts'.

Comment: Happens all the time.  Good to have another set of eyes review your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `inserts: $('input[name=inserts]:checked').val(),` in your jQuery form submit part.

This should work. Try this.

You can not select radio group by ID as there are many radio buttons. By using ID it will select only one and thats not the case with radio group. Radio buttons will be in a group and will share a common name within the group. So we can use a selector based on the name like above.

Comment: If you're going to go that route then use `:checked` selector as well to get only the selected radio button: `$('input[name="inserts"]:checked').val()`.  But you still need an error check in case no buttons are selected.

Comment: Yes @MarekKarbarz you are right. I've just missed that. I've corrected that.